# Creating a list of integers in XML for android

Tags: java, xml, android, arrays, integer

I would like to create a list of Integers in the /res folder of an android project.  However, I want those integers to point resources in /res/raw.  So for example, I would like something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <integer-array name="built_in_sounds">
            <item>@raw/sound</item>
    </integer-array>
</resources>
```

But id doesn't look like I can do that, is there any way to do this?  Or should I just create the list in a java class?

Thank you

Comment: For what do you need that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the correct answer is actually, [TypedArray](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray)

The documentation shows examples of lists of resources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="icons">
        <item>@drawable/home</item>
        <item>@drawable/settings</item>
        <item>@drawable/logout</item>
    </array>
    <array name="colors">
        <item>#FFFF0000</item>
        <item>#FF00FF00</item>
        <item>#FF0000FF</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

And the code to retrieve the values:

```
Resources res = getResources();
TypedArray icons = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);
Drawable drawable = icons.getDrawable(0);

TypedArray colors = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);
int color = colors.getColor(0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally found out how to do this.  What I did, was just create a database.  The database stored all of the primitives I needed to store, and than pointers to the objects that I needed to reference.  Apparently the android SDK comes with support for SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in XML without a database, see:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer